Around Jensen inequality for expectations
Greatings all,
I'm going around in circles a small step in a demo:
$X$ and $Y$ are two random variables defined on $\mathbb{R}$, independant, with $\mathbb{E}[Y]=0$. $\phi$ is a convex function on $\mathbb{R}$. My aim is to compare $\mathbb{E}[\phi(X)]$ and $\mathbb{E}[\phi(X-Y)]$.
A straight application of Jensen's inequality and fact that $\mathbb{E}[Y]=0$ gives
$$
\phi(\mathbb{E}[X]) \leq \mathbb{E}[\phi(X-Y)]. 
$$
But then...
Thanks in advance!

Oh of course, and also true for non independant variables. Thanks!
